# Vector minus its orthogonal projection is the orthogonal projection on the complement?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

*Assume v is a vector of space V, U is a subspace of V .Pr is the orthogonal Projection- on the left side it is on U, and on the right side it's on the orthogonal complement of U. Is it right this equation? (you can ignore the ^2, doesn't matter..) I wasn't sure if on the right side it is indeed the orthogonal projection of the complement of U, or simply some vector of the complement of U*

$$\|\mathbf v-\mathbf{\rm Pr}_{_U}\mathbf{(v)}\|^2=\|\mathbf{\rm Pr}_{_U^{\,\,\,\bot}}\mathbf{(v)}\|^2$$

Comment: It may be helpful to draw a picture.

Comment: I did and I think it's correct what I wrote.. what do you think?

Comment: The same as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you should be able to prove easily from the definition of $\text{proj}_U$ that
$$ \mathbf v = \text{proj}_U\mathbf v + \text{proj}_{U^\perp}\mathbf v$$
for all $\mathbf v\in V$.